# A circular reference was detected EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, json.net

Ok, I am getting this error:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Asset_AED71699FAD007BF6F823A5F022DB9888F62EBBD9E422BBB11D7A191CD784288'.

I get what it means. My code was generated from VisualStudioTools and it generated all my POCOs with virtual navigation properties and mapped the relationships.
I am happy with that and I want the lazy loading.

Here is an example of my user class:

```
public partial class User : IdentityUser
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Assets = new List<Asset>();
        this.Categories = new List<Category>();
        this.Collections = new List<Collection>();
        this.Comments = new List<Comment>();
        this.LocalIntegrations = new List<LocalIntegration>();
        this.Pages = new List<Page>();
        this.Ratings = new List<Rating>();
        this.Themes = new List<Theme>();
        this.ForbiddenCategories = new List<Category>();
        this.ForbiddenPages = new List<Page>();
    }

    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedById { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateModified { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string LinkedIn { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string Facebook { get; set; }
    public string Google { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CredentialId { get; set; }
    public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public bool CanEditOwn { get; set; }
    public bool CanEdit { get; set; }
    public bool CanDownload { get; set; }
    public bool RequiresApproval { get; set; }
    public bool CanApprove { get; set; }
    public bool CanSync { get; set; }
    public bool AgreedTerms { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LocalIntegration> LocalIntegrations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Theme> Themes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> MemberOf { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> ForbiddenCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Page> ForbiddenPages { get; set; }
}
```

and my group class looks like this:

```
public partial class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        this.ForbiddenCategories = new List<Category>();
        this.ForbiddenPages = new List<Page>();
        this.Members = new List<User>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public bool Preset { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> CanEdit { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> CanEditOwn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> CanDownload { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> RequiresApproval { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> CanApprove { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool CanSync { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateModified { get; set; }
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedById { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> ForbiddenCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Page> ForbiddenPages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Members { get; set; }
}
```

I read that in order to stop circular references, you could do something like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Get()
{
    try
    {
        using (var service = new UserService(new CompanyService()))
        {
            var u = from user in await service.GetAll()
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = user.Id,
                        UserName = user.UserName,
                        Email = user.Email,
                        IsApproved = user.IsApproved,
                        IsLockedOut = user.IsLockedOut,
                        MemberOf = user.MemberOf
                    };

            return new JsonResult { Data = new { success = true, users = u } }; // Return our users
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { success = false, error = ex.Message } };
    }
}
```

but it fails when returning the users because of **MemberOf**.
The circular reference is with the **User**, which has a **Collection** and each **Asset** has a **User** who created it.

Is there a way to get it to only do lazy loading on the first POCO (in this case the **User** class) so that it only loads the MemberOf, Assets, etc. but not the rest (i.e. not User > Assets > User)??

**Update 1**

evanmcdonnal suggested that it might be an issue with the **JsonResult** rather than my POCO classes, so I decided to have a look if there was a way to verify that.
Basically I created a **JsonNetResult** class that inherited from **JsonResult** and I overrode **ExecuteResult**. This is what it looks like:

```
public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType) ? ContentType : "application/json";

        if (ContentEncoding != null)
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;

        if (Data == null)
            return;

        // If you need special handling, you can call another form of SerializeObject below
        var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Formatting.Indented);
        response.Write(serializedObject);
    }
}
```

so my method looks like this now:

```
    public async Task<JsonNetResult> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var service = new UserService(new CompanyService()))
            {
                var u = from user in await service.GetAll()
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = user.Id,
                            UserName = user.UserName,
                            Email = user.Email,
                            IsApproved = user.IsApproved,
                            IsLockedOut = user.IsLockedOut,
                            MemberOf = user.MemberOf
                        };

                return new JsonNetResult { Data = new { success = true, users = u } }; // Return our users
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new JsonNetResult { Data = new { success = false, error = ex.Message } };
        }
    }
```

and when I run this, I get the same error as before but it shows in more details. It actually states this:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Asset_AED71699FAD007BF6F823A5F022DB9888F62EBBD9E422BBB11D7A191CD784288'. Path 'users[0].MemberOf[0].Company.Assets[0].Categories[0].Assets'.

Now I am going to check to see if I can change the recursion limit :(

Comment: Are you sure it's not coming from the `JsonResult` class? I haven't worked with that myself however json.NET has a flag which says whether or not circular references are allowed, by default I believe they are not. `JsonResult` has a property called `RecursionLimit` which could very well be the same thing (structures with circular references are recursive by nature), perhaps that value is set to null or 0?

Comment: How can I check if it is coming from the JsonResult class? When I use fiddler it is stating the problem is from System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal which suggests it might be the JsonResult because everything else uses JSON.Net?

Comment: Sorry for the long delayed response. I put in an answer that should solve your problem :)

Comment: Did you find correct solution? If found please update this question to make me know it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding [DataContract(IsReference = true)] to your class. This will serialise your objects using reference ids and should solve circular reference problems.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update I'm going to assume the current value for `RecursionLimit` is the problem. The docs for that property are relatively sparse but that's okay they can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.recursionlimit(v=vs.118).aspx

I believe you can resolve the issue by replacing your current return line with the following lines of code;

```
JsonResult retVal = new JsonResult();
retVal.RecursionLimit = 1000; //maybe parameteraize this?
reVal.Data = = new { success = true, users = u };
return retVal;
```

**EDIT:** After your update I know how easily solve the problem as your exception is now thrown by `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and I've solved this before :)

Based on your update you could easily fix this by changing some code in `ExecuteResult` (this option I'm more confident in as I actually have it implemented in my current project, I personally have not used the `JsonResult` class and my previous suggestion is just me leveraging my general knowledge of json.NET). You can call an overload of `SerializeObject` like sample below and it will now throw when you have circular references;

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourInstanceToSerialize, Formatting.Indented,
 new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize });
```

The available values for `ReferenceLoopHandling` can be found here; http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ReferenceLoopHandling.htm I believe the default is 0 which is why your code is throwing. Since you already updated with those changes I think I'd advise going with the second method (I at least know it will work) but feel free to try the first one too.

Answer (score 0):

Ive found turning OFF lazy loading for these queries works. Simply ensure your query selects all it needs to via "include" if needed.
Then before the query:

```
efContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```